# How can I solve this delay differential equation?

Tags: delay-differential-equations

I'm solving a problem where I encountered a DDE:
$$ y'(t)=r\left(1-\frac{y(t-q)}{C}\right)y(t)$$
Where $r$, $q$ and $C$ are real constants.

Now, with $q=0$ it's pretty easy and the solution is just a logistic function. But what if $q\neq0$? I can easily write a program that numerically solves this, but is there a method to actually find $y(t)$?

Comment: Does that y in the y(t-q) term represent y(t) itself?

Comment: Yes, it's $y(t)$

Comment: Since you can rescale $t$, without loss of generality you can assume $q = 1$. Still, [delay differential equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_differential_equation) are difficult to do analytically.

Comment: @eyeballfrog oh, thanks for the link, I'll definitely check it out.

Comment: Why the downvote? Can I improve the question?

Comment: We can also get this to a single delay parameter with the substitutions $y(t) = Cu(rt)$, $s = rt$ and $a = qr$, giving $u'(s) =u(s)\left[1 -u(s-a)\right]$. A different rescaling of $t$ can also give $u'(s) = a u(s) \left[ 1- u(s - 1)\right]$.

Comment: Being a delay differential equation, it's far from "ordinary".

Comment: @RobertIsrael I didn't know DDEs, edited.